# Sass - mixing setting 2 layered backgrounds

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I've been trying to create a mixin for something I repeat all along my website, but it doesn't work.

The mixin I want to create generate an icon with two images, both images are used as background-image and are overlayed. Basically you should have with it as result, a circle background with an image applied as background-image and on top the actual icon which is put as well using css background-image.

Here is the mixin I did.

```
@mixin coloredIcons($width,$height,$radius,$nameImgA,$nameImgB,$extensionA,$extensionB,$bg-size1,$bg-size2){
       width: $width;
       height:$height;
       background:url("../imgs/#{$nameImgA}.#{$extensionA}") no-repeat center center,
       url("../imgs/#{$nameImgB}.#{$extensionB}") center center;
       -moz-border-radius: $radius;
       -webkit-border-radius:$radius;
       -o-border-radius:$radius;
       border-radius: $radius;
       background-size: $bg-size1 $bg-size1, $bg-size2;
};
```

Here is the way I included it to be applied to my red class.

```
.red{
 @include coloredIcons(200px,200px,50%,"idea","bg_icon_red","png","jpg",200px,"cover");
 }
```

And obvously It doesn't work, haven't yet found a way to fix it.
However here is the pure css version which works like a charm.

```
.red{
// @include coloredIcons(200px,200px,50%,"idea","bg_icon_red","png","jpg",200px,"cover");
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background:url('../imgs/icons/idea_grey.png') no-repeat center center,
 url("../imgs/bg_icon_red.jpg") center center;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-border-radius:50%;
 -o-border-radius:50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
background-size: 200px 200px,cover
}
```

Your help is welcome...

Comment: Some more detail of the problem besides "doesn't work" would be helpful. Is [interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) the issue? That said, getting that long list of arguments in the right order is going to be a chore. Using some [default values](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixin-arguments) and calling the mixin with [keyword arguments](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#keyword_arguments_2) would help.

Comment: Look closer at the compiled vs hand written.  The paths to the images are different.  Voting to close this one as a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As cimmanon mentioned, check your image path and remove the double quotes on your last parameter.

```
 @include coloredIcons(200px,200px,50%,"idea_grey","bg_icon_red","png","jpg",200px,cover);
```

Generates the same output as your pure css version.

Comment: We prefer to close "simple typographical" questions rather than answer them since they are not useful to future visitors.